# Plugin development - JOptionPane Warning message is too small

Tags: java, plugins, joptionpane, xtext

I am developing a plugin for my language I created using xtext.
In my plugin I need to show a warning message in some case. This is my code:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unable to Extract", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
```

This is how it's look: 
[image]
This is very small, why it's happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: why no use SWT/Jface instead of Swing? why show a dialog at all - this wont work in standalone mode e.g. on a build server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SWT/JFace instead of Swing. But i still doubt it is a good idea to show the same warning

- During Editing
- During Build

And it might not work in standalone mode or headless mode since there is no ui then.

```
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec() [
            MessageDialog.openWarning(Display.current.activeShell, "xxx", "yyyy")
        ]
```